# JQuery if statement not working (AJAX/PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

[image]I'm using Jquery & ajax & php to create a login form.
Everything is working except for the sucess function.
When the response from the php file is retrieved, even if it's true it will run the else statement.

JQuery/Ajax code

```
    $('document').ready(function()
{
  $("#btnLogin").click(function(){

   email=$("#userEmail").val();
   password=$("#userPassword").val();
   $.ajax({

       type : 'POST',
       url  : 'userLogin.php',
       //data : {userEmail: email, userPassword: password},
       data: "userEmail="+email+"&userPassword="+password,
       success :  function(response)
       {      
         if(response==='true'){     
            //login sucess animation  
              $("#btnLogin").html('<img src="media/login.gif" /> &nbsp; Iniciando sessão ...');
              setTimeout(' window.location.href = "index.php"; ',4000);
         }
         else{
             //error message
            $("#error").fadeIn(5000, function(){      
                $("#errorlogin").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; '+response+' !</div>');
                //$("#btnLogin").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp; Sign In');
            })
          }
         },
       beforeSend: function()
       {            
            $("#loginerror").fadeOut();
            $("#btn-login").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span>');
       }
   });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Even if the response is equal to true it will run the else statement (the alert is shown  saying 'true !' instead of the login animation)

Comment: Do a `console.log(response)` and show what you see in the console here.

Comment: Can you alert(response) for me please

Comment: First check whether you're getting `true` as string or boolean as AJAX response.

Comment: Looks like I had an old
 <script type="text/javascript">
 //window.location="index.php";
 </script>
sitting in my php file after echoing "true" and it appeared in the console logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an old`<script type="text/javascript">
    //window.location="index.php";
    </script>`

sitting in my php file after echoing the response and that was what was causing this mess.
I was only able to see this after doing what gaganshera suggested (using console.log(response).

Answer (score 0):

Returning a simple string can be buggy due to possible extra whitespace.

Try trimming the string or even better return json

```
if(response.trim()==='true'){
```